# Groovy cannot run batch command "Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": error=2, No such file or directory"

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, cmd

I'm trying to run some command on a Windows agent with `cmd` using the groovy `String.execute()` in a Jenkins pipeline.

I know that there exists the `bat` script which I can use and I intentionally don't want to use it in this specific case since it bloats the logs and the Blue Ocean plugin has a limit of number of steps it can shows for any stage.

Basically what I have is basically some cleanup function that I call very often which does a lot of checks and runs multiple commands (at the moment with `sh` and `bat` in addition to `isUnix()` and similar). The result is usually a very bloated logs of steps like `sh` and `bat` which makes the logs larger and more difficult to analyze.
I decided to use some native way of running shell commands "silently" and only print its stdout and stderr in case the command fails.
I have written such a function that executes the command

```
@ NonCPS
def exec(cmd) {
    def isUnix = Jenkins.instance.getNodes().find { it.getNodeName() == env.NODE_NAME }.toComputer().isUnix()
    cmd = (isUnix ? ["/bin/bash", "-c"] : ["cmd.exe", "/c"]) + [cmd]
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.waitFor()

    def result = [out: proc.in.text.trim(), err: proc.err.text.trim(), exitCode: proc.exitValue()]
    return result
}
```

The above function works perfectly for linux agents but not on Windows. I always get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:415)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:312)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:415)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:312)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Or mainly the following line `Cannot run program "cmd.exe": error=2, No such file or directory`.
I tried replacing "cmd.exe" with the full path "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" or "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe", replace `cmd.exe` with `["start", "cmd.exe", "/C"]`, using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and many others and I cannot make it work.

If I do `"git version".execute()`, that works fine but I cannot run some more complex commands like `"echo hi && git version".execute()` which will print "hi && git version" instead of "hi" and the real git version. I thought maybe the `PATH` environment variable is not set properly so I ran the following command `"set".execute()` which resulted in the same error above ("set" no such file or directory).

I have been trying various combinations of this for the past 2 days and that is not going anywhere.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Found the reason why it is failing on Windows but not on Linux nodes with Jenkins and hit another "harder" wall here.

The problem is that String.exucute() method behaves internally like Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and this uses the runtime environment from the master node even if encapsulated within the node() directive. This basically means that when it was running fine on linux, it was actually running all the time on the master node which is also linux. The reason why it cannot run cmd or start or any similar is because those commands (obviously) do not exist on linux.